# connecting a variable output to send Keys string

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to generate a random number that is six digits and then submit that 6 digit out put to a website.

here is my code:

```
send_code = self.chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[3]/form/span/button").click()
            random_num = random.randrange(000000, 999999)
            (f'{random_num:06}')
            send_random_num = self.chrome_browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input')
            random_num.send_keys(Keys.random_num, Keys.ENTER)
```

the generating the random number is working but for some reason my send_random_num variable is not executing the right commands. I feel like I am formatting this wrong. Keys.(var) just isn't close to right so any suggestions? thanks (using selenium)

Comment: this may be impossible after further researh

Comment: Instead of the last line, try `random_num.send_keys(*[getattr(Keys,i) for i in str(random_num)], Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
@TomRobinson i would need to define send _keys?

Comment: What module are you using?

Comment: Ah, selenium. okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you are using selenium. Maybe next time try adding that as a tag or clearly stating what module you are using. I believe this will work, and I took the liberty clarifying some of your variable names:

```py
button = self.chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[3]/form/span/button")
button.click()
random_num = random.randrange(000000, 999999)
random_code = (f'{random_num:06}')
input = self.chrome_browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input')
input.send_keys(random_code)
```